# How can i use log4php inside functions

Tags: php, function, class, log4php

What is the correct form to use log4php inside a class with functions?

```
<?php
include_once 'log4php-2.3.0/src/main/php/Logger.php';

class template
{
  public static temp1;
  public static temp2;
  Logger::configure($path . '\commons\log4php-2.3.0\config.xml');
  $log = Logger::getLogger('myLogger');

  public static function example1()
  {

  }

  public static function example2()
  {

  }
```

}

How can I call the  `$log->fatal($error);` line for example inside both functions? Should i redeclare the $log in each or how?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example from [**Reference**](https://logging.apache.org/log4php/quickstart.html)

```
// Include and configure log4php
include('log4php/Logger.php');
Logger::configure('config.xml');

/**
 * This is a classic usage pattern: one logger object per class.
 */
class Foo
{
    /** Holds the Logger. */
    private $log;

    /** Logger is instantiated in the constructor. */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // The __CLASS__ constant holds the class name, in our case "Foo".
        // Therefore this creates a logger named "Foo" (which we configured in the config file)
        $this->log = Logger::getLogger(__CLASS__);
    }

    /** Logger can be used from any member method. */
    public function go()
    {
        $this->log->info("We have liftoff.");
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->go();
```

Comment: I'm using this way alredy, problem is i'm getting this error, seems like isn't getting past the construct, Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context.
I'm using this class without doing the new Foo, i'm just calling the functions